# Searching blob using the blob name

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

How we can find out the `Blob` from the `Container` using the `Blob` name ?

Comment: Is this not possible or i asked something wrong ?

Comment: I took a wild guess, but your question doesn't really tell us much. I assume because it's on Stack Overflow that you're writing code, but you don't tell us which language. (The tags indicate C#.) I also don't know what it would mean to "find out the Blob." If you already know the name, what more do you want to find out? The title of the post says "searching," but the text doesn't say anything about searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to do `container.GetBlobReference(name)`?

Comment: yes i tried this but if blob does`nt exist then this function will create it.

Comment: No, it won't. It doesn't do anything except construct a local object. (Try running it with the network cable unplugged.) If what you're trying to do is test whether or not a blob exists, see http://blog.smarx.com/posts/testing-existence-of-a-windows-azure-blob.